# Error in my php code when I try to graph my query table

Tags: php

Due to how I have the information in tables I need to make a union to show cross references.

Tablebrand1 is a name of a table. 2 and 3

```
Tablebrand1

CODE    CROSSREFERENCE
A15     SAMSUNG A10
A16     SAMSUNG A20
A63     SAMSUNG A30

Tablebrand2

CODE    CROSSREFERENCE
X63     SAMSUNG A10
X64     SAMSUNG A20
X65     SAMSUNG A30

Tablebrand3

CODE    CROSSREFERENCE
TOP99   SAMSUNG A10
TOP98   SAMSUNG A20
TOP97   SAMSUNG A30
```

SQL QUERY

```
(SELECT "Tablebrand1" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand1 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
UNION 
(SELECT "Tablebrand2" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand2 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
UNION
(SELECT "Tablebrand3" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand3 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10');
```

The query brings it correctly, but when trying to show it in php I get an error that comes from the query because if I modify it for a simpler query it brings me the data correctly.

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>brand</th><th>code</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
  function __construct($it) {
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
  }

  function current() {
    return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
  }

  function beginChildren() {
    echo "<tr>";
  }

  function endChildren() {
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
  }
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("((SELECT "Tablebrand1" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand1 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
UNION 
(SELECT "Tablebrand2" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand2 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
UNION
(SELECT "Tablebrand3" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand3 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10');");
  $stmt->execute();

  // set the resulting array to associative
  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v;
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

My code is the following and my knowledge of php and union is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not saying what your error message is, but one obvious error is the quotes you are using are not being escaped.
Also you have one `(` too many at the beging of the query (`"((SELECT...`)
So you need to escape the quotes in your query like so

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
  (SELECT \"Tablebrand1\" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
   FROM Tablebrand1 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
  UNION 
  (SELECT \"Tablebrand2\" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
   FROM Tablebrand2 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
  UNION
  (SELECT \"Tablebrand3\" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
   FROM Tablebrand3 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10');"
);
```

alternatively you can use single quotes in the query instead of double quotes like so

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
  (SELECT 'Tablebrand1' AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
   FROM Tablebrand1 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
  UNION 
  (SELECT 'Tablebrand2' AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
   FROM Tablebrand2 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
  UNION
  (SELECT 'Tablebrand3' AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
   FROM Tablebrand3 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10');"
);
```